# Working with Data.Map.StrictMap.Maps using Control.Parallel

Tags: haskell, dictionary, parallel-processing

I have the following code. The `M` prefix designates functions from `Data.Map.Strict`, and `Table` is a type alias for `Data.Map.Strict.Map Mapping Bool`, where `Mapping` is an arbitrary opaque structure.

```
computeCoverage :: Table -> Expr -> Maybe Coverage 
computeCoverage t e = go t True M.empty
  where go src flag targ
          | null src = if flag
                       then Nothing
                       else Just (M.size t, targ)
          | otherwise = let ((m, b), rest) = M.deleteFindMin src 
                            result = interpret e m
                            flag' = result && flag in 
              go rest flag' (if b == result then targ else M.insert m b targ)
```

I would like to be able to use `Control.Parallel` to perform this with as much parallelism as possible. However, I'm not sure how to do this. Based on reading `Data.Map.Strict`, it seems what you're supposed to do is call `splitRoot`, then do whatever parallel stuff you want on the resulting list, then recombine (I guess?). Have I basically got the right idea? If not, what should I do instead to parallelize the code above?

Comment: And what is `Coverage`? What is the high-level overview of this algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a contrived example. You just use `parMap` over `M.splitRoot m`:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import System.Environment

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-2) + fib (n-1)

theMap :: Int -> M.Map Int Int
theMap n = M.fromList [ (x, 33 + mod x 3) | x <- [1..n] ]

isInteresting n = mod (fib n) 2 == 0

countInteresting :: M.Map Int Int -> Int
countInteresting m = length $ filter isInteresting (M.elems m)

doit :: Int -> [Int]
doit n = parMap rseq countInteresting (M.splitRoot $ theMap n)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  ( arg1 : _) <- getArgs
  let n = read arg1
  print $ doit n
```

Note, however these caveats:

- the splits may not be of equal size
- use `splitRoot` if working with a Map is helpful for your computation; this particular example doesn't benefit from the Map structure of root - it could have just parMapped over the elements.